# How to fetch a file from a URL

Tags: python

I have a URL, for example

```
url = "www.example.com/file/processing/path/excefile.xls"
```

This URL downloads an excel file directly when I paste it in a browser.
How can I use python to download this file? That is, if I run the python code the above URL should open in a browser and download the excel file.

Comment: why do you need the browser? Are you just interested in downloading a file?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't necessarily need to go through the browser, you can use the `urllib` module to save a file to a specified location.

```
import urllib

url = 'http://www.example.com/file/processing/path/excelfile.xls'
local_fname = '/home/John/excelfile.xls'
filename, headers = urllib.retrieveurl(url, local_fname)
```

http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`webbrowser` module](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html):

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open(url)
```

Comment: I've only just discovered this, but what a jewel of knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely look into the awesome [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-get-request) lib.